# LWC lightnig input type date max value dynamically

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightninginput, lightning-inputfield, js

LWC lightnig input type date max value dynamically
I'm trying to add max Date as 2 years from now. Getting the error ass add_years is not defined

Any suggestion would be great..

Html:

```
<lightning-input class="dateBoxWidth" type="date" date-style="short" value={select.recordValue} onchange={handleChnage} min={todayDate} max={renewExpiryDate}></lightning-input>


<lightning-input class="dateBoxWidth" type="date" date-style="short" value={select.recordValue} onchange={handleChnage} min={todayDate} max={renewExpiryDate}></lightning-input>
```

js:

```
var newDate = new Date(); 
        this.todayDate = newDate.toLocaleDateString();
var ExpiryDate = new Date();
        this.renewExpiryDate = add_years(ExpiryDate, 2).toLocaleDateString();
```

Comment: Where is the `add_years()` defined? If you have defined it at class level, then call it using `this.`

Comment: I didn't used it or defined anywhere except in above place .. Please suggest in code.. I'll understand.. Thank you for reply @rahulgawale